# Why is the pink boundary not disappearing in this graph?

Tags: plotting

Why the pink boundary is not disappearing in this graph. In this type of graph, I am facing the issue that you can see in the image.

```
y = 0.75; z = 0.5; s = 0.25;
\[Lambda] = 1.25; \[Mu] = 1.75; \[Nu] = 1.5; \[Rho] = 0.5;
\[Theta] = 0.5; \[Tau] = 2;
\[Alpha] = 0.25; \[Beta] = 0.75; c = 1;
\[Omega] = \[Lambda]*x + \[Mu]*y + \[Nu]*z + \[Rho]*s + Sinh[(1 - \[Theta]) (-4*\[Alpha]*\[Lambda]^3)*t^((\[Theta] + 1)/2)] + \[Tau];
B1 = c + (6*\[Alpha]*\[Lambda]*Cosh[\[Omega]])/(\[Beta]*Sinh[\[Omega]])
slice = SliceContourPlot3D[B1, r == -7, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 1}, {r, -7, 12}, PlotRange -> {-5, 4.6}, Contours -> 30, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ColorFunction -> Hue, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code as code along with the image....If you put you mouse over the pink, you should see an error message, I think.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code (InputForm) rather than just an image so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start with the [tour]! We [expect this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html) No imgages. 
❌. An example of what you expect as output
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add copy-paste-able code (not images) so that forum participants can copy and paste it to their notebook environments to replicate the errors or difficulties you face. The comments and answers will consequently be more focused. Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: Michael E2 the error message appearing is "None is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive." But I did not get the point.

Comment: I don't get any error, just a reasonable looking plot. My guess would be a lingering definition. Try restarting the kernel and running the same code again.